# solution set of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a system of linear equations with 3 variables and solution set $\{(a, b, c) | a^2 =  b\}$?

My answer is no but I'm not sure how to explain it.

**Edit:** can't I just say that if $ax+by+cz=ax+a^2y+cz=d$ is the equation then also $2ax+4a^2y+2cz=2ax+2a^2y+2cz+2a^2y=\color{red}d$. but if I multiply $ax+a^2y+cz=d$ by 2 then I get that $2ax+2a^2y+2cz=2d$. then if I substitute this into the previous equation I get that $2d+2a^2y=d\Rightarrow d=-2a^2y$ which also means that $(0, -2a^2, 0)$ is solution, but it's true only for $a=0$.

Is this correct way to prove it?

Comment: how do you get this red d,moreover what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Semsem: I just assumed that this is some equation from the system of linear equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of a system of linear equations is a vector subspace (the kernel of the mapping associated with the system) displaced by a vector (the particular solution).

If two variables in the solution have a quadratic dependence, any translation of the solution space will still have this dependence, since a translation just adds a constant to each vector component. Thus, the kernel of the linear map won't be a vector space, and won't be the solution of any homogeneous system.

Answer (score 1):

There are some hidden assumptions here.  If your underlying field is $\mathbb{F}_2$, then the condition $a^2=b$ is equivalent to $a=b$, and in this case the system $\{a-b=0\}$ is a system that has the desired solution set.

If your underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$, then $(1,1,0)$ and $(3,9,0)$ are solutions, so by linearity $(2,5,0)$ is a solution, which is not in the desired solution set. [there is a fairly easy-to-prove theorem that states that the midpoint of two solutions is also a solution.]